# How fair is it to forbid a user to delete his own post?

Tags: discussion, policy

Yes we can all read license of terms and we know they can write anything they want. But how fair is this situation? This policiy is %99 good for StackExchange and %1 for community. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 10):

I (as a user) only see benefits, because it maximises the volume of content available to me and prevents other users taking away what has been given to the community. For example it stops people from asking questions, getting solutions and then selfishly deleting the post to keep the content to themselves. It also prevents the rare cases of users becoming bitter for some reason and trying to delete all their content out of spite.

You mention the license terms, and hold them up as a negative, but you still have options, even within these terms.

1. Obviously, you can choose not to post in the first place if you aren't willing to give over your content to the community (under the creative commons license)
2. If you post content from elsewhere and later discover that you didn't actually have the rights to do so (eg it's bound by some other license or copyright terms), you can flag it for a mod to remove
3. If you just decide that you don't want to be associated with the content [you have the right to have your name removed from the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts), and it just becomes "anonymous" content

Also, as an aside, yes, the licence terms are beneficial for StackExchange too, but they could have been much more draconian about it if they didn't care about the community. CC-BY-SA is a pretty end-user friendly licence to be bound to. Yes, you "lose" the right to delete your content, but you gain the right to use *all* the content *ever* posted on *any* StackExchange site, in *any* way you see fit (*including* commercial), so long as you share alike and give attribution. Seems like a pretty good deal to me...

Answer (score 9):

I don't see anything wrong with it - there's nothing unfair about it at all. Stack Exchange does that so that people don't ask their questions, get a good answer, and then delete it - the whole point of Stack Exchange is to serve as a repository of questions and answers. Easy deletion of good questions would go against the purpose of the network.